# Calculating Rollup Fields in Lookup Relationship (For Example: Account and Opportunity)

Tags: trigger, lookup, roll-up-summary

I have written a trigger for my scenario, where I want the Sum of Amount of all the Opportunities to be stored in a custom field "Total_Amount__c" in Account Object whenever there is an update in Amount field of Opportunity.

I have made use of Bulkification and best practices according to me and the trigger is working as desired. Please let me know if this trigger code can be optimized.

Thanks in advance!

trigger code:-

```
public class AmountCalculator{

public static void onBeforeUpdate(List<Opportunity> opps){
Set<Id> accountsUpdated = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> updatedOppsAccId = new Set<Id>();
List<Account> updatedAccounts = new List<Account>();
Map<Id,Decimal> mapTot = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
Map<Id, Decimal> oppAmounts = new Map<Id, Decimal>();

for(Opportunity opp : opps){
    oppAmounts.put(opp.Id, opp.Amount);
    updatedOppsAccId.add(opp.AccountId);
}

List<Opportunity> accOpps = [Select Id, Account.Id, Name, Amount, Account.Total_amount__c from Opportunity where Account.Id in :updatedOppsAccId];
    System.debug('Fetched Opportunities are: '+accOpps);

    for(Opportunity opp : accOpps){
        Decimal tempAmount = 0.0;
        if(accountsUpdated.contains(opp.AccountId)){
            if(oppAmounts.containsKey(opp.Id)){
                tempAmount = oppAmounts.get(opp.Id);
                Decimal recOppAmt = mapTot.get(opp.AccountId);
                mapTot.put(opp.AccountId, (tempAmount + recOppAmt));

        }
            else{
                tempAmount = mapTot.get(opp.AccountId);
                mapTot.put(opp.AccountId, (tempAmount + opp.Amount));
            }
        }
        else{
            if(oppAmounts.containsKey(opp.AccountId)){
                tempAmount = oppAmounts.get(opp.AccountId);
                mapTot.put(opp.AccountId, tempAmount);
                accountsUpdated.add(opp.AccountId);
            }
            else{
                mapTot.put(opp.AccountId, opp.Amount);
                accountsUpdated.add(opp.AccountId);
            }
        }
    }


    for(Account acc : [Select Id, Name, Total_Amount__c from Account where Id in: mapTot.keySet()]){

        acc.Total_Amount__c = mapTot.get(acc.Id);
        updatedAccounts.add(acc);
    }

    if(updatedAccounts.size() > 0){
        update updatedAccounts;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I personally find it confusing when you delete, undelete, re-delete and then re-ask your questions. It also removes useful context.

Comment: Code review is not really on topic for this site. If you want that, there is a specific **[codereview.se]** exchange. Also, you are reinventing the wheel here. I highly recommend you simply install **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)** and *configure* your rollups instead. ***Clicks Not Code***.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is not to write any code at all. You can create a Roll up Summary Field on Account and sum the Opportunity amounts automatically. No code.

Comment: @davidScach Can we create Rollup Summary field on lookup?. Isn't it available only in Master Detail relationship?

Comment: Opportunity to Account is a special case. It will work.

Comment: @davidScach thanks for the answer but I am more concerned about other cases i.e, Lookup relationships where we have to involve code to achieve it.

Comment: Perhaps the question should have been written to account for all that. As written, there is no need for code. Please mark my answer as correct and then ask a new question with more specific requirements. However, you won't get too far, as (as people have said) this is not a code review site.